# Node: Assign an exposed function to an object's property in a different file

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, properties

I have an express-based REST API service. One API receives two parameters:

- id
- type

The API is supposed to resolve the `id` into some details and perform a serial of common tasks for all types. The function to resolve the id is different base on the variable `type`.

I'm trying to achieve this by creating `1 + n` reference files, where the `1` is the file containing the flow of resolving id and all common tasks, and `n` refers to files containing specific resolution function for id base on type. Code sample as below.

- type1.js

  ```
  module.exports.resolveId = function(id, callback) {...callback};
  module.exports.otherFunctions....
  ```
- common.js

  ```
  var type1Lib = require('./type1.js'); 
  var resFunc = {type1:typeLib.resolveId};
  function performTasks(id, type, callback) {
      async.auto(
          resolve:function(cb) {
              resFunc[type](id, cb);
          },
          otherFunc:['resolve', function(cb) {cb}]
      }, callback)
  }
  ```

Upon executing to the line `resFunc[type](id, cb)`, the code crashes because `resFunc[type]` is undefined.

I tried to declare the function first in type1.js

```
    function resolveId (id, callback) {...callback};
    module.exports.resolveId = resolveId;
```

but this doesn't help either.

Am I missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `type` is something like 1, 2, 3 ... then your require call should be in the `performTasks` body:

```
function performTasks(id, type, callback) {
  var resFunc = require('./type' + type); // and, no extension needed here
  async.auto(
    resolve:function(cb) {
      resFunc(id, cb);
    },
    otherFunc:['resolve', function(cb) {cb}]
  }, callback)
}
```

and your module would be :

```
function resolveId (id, callback) {...callback};
module.exports = resolveId;
```

Alternatively you can `require` all the modules in advance :

```
var resFuncs = {
  1: require('./type1'),
  2: require('./type2'),
  3: require('./type3')
};

function performTasks(id, type, callback) {
  async.auto(
    resolve:function(cb) {
      resFuncs[type](id, cb);
    },
    otherFunc:['resolve', function(cb) {cb}]
  }, callback)
}
```

**Edit**

'module.exports' is simply the variable defined in the module file and it is exactly what require() call returns. You can assign a single function to it or an object consisting of multiple variables, objects or functions.

Comment: Bulent, thanks for the reply. My type is a string, and each type.js contains more than one function. So I can't really do module.exports = resolveId; Plus, what's the difference between module.exports and module.exports.resolveId fundamentally? I'm trying to understand this in theory level too.

Comment: You can have multiple functions, it will only affect what you will put after the last dot of `require('./typeX').` . If you do module.exports =  function then you can have only a single function  export and require call should end with );

Comment: Both module.exports and module.exports.resovleId are assigning a function to a property in nature, right? If they're the same in nature, why would one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: 'module.exports' is just a variable. You can use it however you want. Added a small explanation to the answer. I suggest reading this : https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/

Comment: I understand this. Is module.exports.resolveId not a variable? In my opinion, it is. If not, what is it?